# How to create a custom log and stream it to cloudwatch through AWS Cloudformation template in elasticbeanstalk ?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to stream a custom log in AWS cloudwatch through AWS Cloudformation template using elasticbeanstalk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar requirement a few years back. In our case, we have deployed a tomcat application via ElasticBeanstalk with the use of a Cloudformation Template. Whenever there will be an ERROR log in the Catalina logs, the alert will be sent by Cloudwatch Alarm. The Cloudwatch setup is done by ebextensions. For the implementation details, you can refer to the below link: 
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/enable-alert-error-pattern-elasticbeanstalk-priyanka-sharma/